# Alfresco with custom authentication webservice

Tags: rest, authentication, alfresco

We have a custom authentication service which accepts a parameter over a REST service and provides a json response. Based on the response we redirect the user. I wish to integrate this webservice with our new Alfresco Box.

Is there a way to do custom base authentication instead of using LDAP or inbuilt SSO plugin?

Comment: I think, we can override the configuration section on share side, but I need to check on that also. Check this section <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Remote"> in share-config.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly...

1. Implement your custom [remote user mapper](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.0a/root/projects/web-client/source/java/org/alfresco/web/app/servlet/DefaultRemoteUserMapper.java):

   ```
   package best.package.ever;
   import org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.external.DefaultRemoteUserMapper;

   public class CustomRemoteUserMapper extends DefaultRemoteUserMapper {
       public boolean canHandle(HttpServletRequest request) {
           return true; // TODO
       }   
       public String getTrustedUserId(HttpServletRequest request) {
           // TODO: validate & authorize... e.g. based on trusted Json Web Token
           return "trusted.user.id"; // TODO
       }
       public String getRemoteUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
           if (canHandle(request)) {
               return getTrustedUserId(request);
           } else {
               return super.getRemoteUser(request);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Put your library best-package-ever.jar into **tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\lib**
3. Declare your custom bean and inject it into [RemoteUserMapper](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/management/subsystems/ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java) bean: **tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\authentication-custom-context.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
   <beans> 
       <bean id="customRemoteUserMapper" class="best.package.ever.CustomRemoteUserMapper">
           <property name="personService" ref="PersonService"/>
           <property name="authorityService" ref="AuthorityService" />
       </bean>
       <bean id="RemoteUserMapper" class="org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory">
           <property name="applicationContextManager">
               <ref bean="Authentication" />
           </property>
           <property name="interfaces">
               <list>
                   <value>org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.external.RemoteUserMapper</value>
                   <value>org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ActivateableBean</value>
               </list>
           </property>
           <property name="sourceBeanName">
               <value>customRemoteUserMapper</value> <!-- extending remoteUserMapper -->
           </property>
       </bean>
   </beans>
   ```

Comment: I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Please let us know if you have any other questions.